# Crossing the Canadian border with all your camping/mountaineering/mountain biking gear?

Tags: canada, land-borders

I am traveling in my Subaru Outback. Its filled up with my clothes, food for camping, mountaineering and climbing gear and my mountain bike.

What kind of problems might I run into during border crossing?

Comment: A longer search, should they elect to search you, than you would endure without all that gear.

Answer (score 6):

Normally one to should have no issue. If your car is filled to the brim with content they may ask you to subject to an inspection. Looking for drugs, weapons, etc. So long as you don't have any weapons you'll be ok.
You will be asked questions about where you're going, how long you're going to be here, the usual. Canada gets a lot of a people coming for "sports tourism", camping, etc. I assume you're American and with an American passport you should have no real issue entering. The worst is they'll ask you to fill out an entry form and provide you with a visitor report with a date you must leave by (usually indicated based on when you said you're planning to leave).

Comment: Guns are of course an exception. Just worth mentioning.

Comment: Are there no restrictions on bringing food into Canada from the US? The question explicitly mentions food.